# extension vs global-modules in wildfly

Tags: wildfly-8

I am new to wildfly.  Can anyone give the difference between extension and global-modules in wildfly standalone.xml.

As per the Wildfly documentation an extension is a module that extends the core capabilities of the server.  But global-module is also provide the common dependencies to the wep applications.  So, where is the difference.

Thanks
Senthil

Comment: That definition really explains it. An extension is for extending WildFly. A global-module just adds a module dependency to deployments.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  But, If I want to have some modules to be available to all web applications then should I add it to extension or global-module?

Answer (score 0):

As you underlined in your comment, you want to add some dependencies to multiple web applications.
If you want to do that a global-module would be fine. A global modules add dependencies to the classpath of all your deployments.
This is suitable for interceptors or other cross cutting concers over multiple applications in the same server deployment.

An extension would be something that the wildfly core extends and integrates on a deeper level in the wildfly. Technically it is still a module but deeper integrated than a global module.

Hope this answers helps you, although it is a little late.